# Is it incorrect to return Task.Factory.StartNew( ()=>{ ; } )?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Here's the code i keep seeing--

```
public Task PossiblyAsyncOperation(bool condition)
    {
        //this condition means i need to do something async, for sure
        if (condition)
             return AsyncOp();

        //since it didnt hit the above condition
        //we're not doing the async op now
        //.....this just feels wrong
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ; });
    }
```

Is there a better way to return when you're not actually going to end up running an async operation? Or do you have to return a new, started task? Is there a performance hit for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `Task.FromResult<T>`  if you're using .Net 4.5

```
return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
```

Otherwise you could write your own implementation

```
public static Task CreateEmptyTask()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    tsc.SetResult(null);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

As the comment points out, you may be able to cache this task, however beware that you must prevent it from being disposed. For example the following would throw an exception:

```
public static readonly Task EmptyTask = Task.FromResult<object>(null);

Task t = EmptyTask;
t.Dispose();
((IAsyncResult)t).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Comment: based upon the research i did on your post (which led me here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228607.aspx) it seems like this is how MSFT would prefer this be done. thanks for schooling me.

Comment: Tasks can be re-used. Cache it in a static readonly field, and you'll have less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just create a [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) and then return the Task property.  This is a way to essentially skip the async call altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing anything and `Task` is a class, so a *reference*,  why not simply return a `null`..

```
public Task PossiblyAsyncOperation(bool condition)
{
     //this condition means i need to do something async, for sure
     if (condition)
          return AsyncOp();

     //since it didnt hit the above condition
     //we're not doing the async op now
     //.....this just feels wrong
     return null; //RETURN NULL
}
```

Comment: because you typically .ContinueWith() afterwards... i guess i could null check that part

Comment: I don't believe `null` is expected by the framework or most user code, on grounds of `.ContinueWith()` and the fact that `null` is not awaitable.